# How do I pass current windows username from the telerik report viewer to the associated report parameter to query results for that user only

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, telerik-reporting

This is the code behind for the report viewer.  It does check the local logged on user to give those listed permission to view the report.  I want to pass the "domainname\user" to the parameter of a report to return results only for the logged in user.

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Intranet.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="2021BudgetVsActualViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="Company.Departments.Accounting._2021BudgetVsActualReports._2021BudgetVsActualViewer" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.14.507, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" namespace="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms" tagprefix="telerik" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <%
    
string ADusername;

ADusername = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];

ADusername = ADusername.ToLower();

switch(ADusername)
{
    case "domainname\\jdoe":
    case " domainname \\administrator":
   case " domainname \\bsmith":
                     
%> 
    <telerik:ReportViewer ID="New" runat="server" Height="840px" Width="1556px">
<typereportsource typename="Company.Departments.Accounting._2021BudgetVsActualReports._2021NewBudgetVsActualReport, Company, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"></typereportsource>
</telerik:ReportViewer>
    <br />

<%
        break;
    default:
        Response.Write("You do not have permission to view these reports");
        break;
}

%>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What do you mean "use in visual studio 2012"? As in, in some build script/event? Or are you conflating VS with a programming language?

Comment: Simpler than that. Using Visual Studio 2012  I'm just creating reports with report viewers using sql queries in the report.  I want to write one report that pulls the current username and assigning that to the report parameter so that John Doe, for instance, only see's his sales numbers in a report, or someone else only sees theirs...  Instead of writing 10 reports for 10 different sales people.  I know how to write the SQL Query, I just can't figure out how to assign the username to a variable I can "make it equal to" in the query.

Comment: Show some code - as is your question isn't very clear

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SYSTEM_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/system-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) TSQL function to return the name of the currently logged-in user.

Comment: The user is accessing the report through an internal webserver.  The connection string to the database for every report viewer that loads uses a SQL login that is the same username, not the local windows logged in user.  Here is the question  In each report viewer I've used a switch/case to allow the report to be viewed by only those in the case section of code so I know that the project knows who is logged in.  I'm trying to pass that information into the parameter of the actual report to filter query results just for the person logged in.